# How do i replace " character in Java?

Tags: java, parsing

I have

```
String a = "data=\"0\"1\"1\"1\"1\"0\"0\"0\"0\"0\"0\"1\"1\"1\"1\"0\"0\"0\"0\"0\"1\"1\"1\"1\"1\\\\";
```

How can i replace

- `"` to `\"`
- and `\` to `\\`

?

```
String result = a.replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

OR

```
String result = a.replace(""", "\"");
```

Comment: Did you test that? Did the second variant even compile?

Comment: why not try and see what happens ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String result = a.replace("\\","\\\\").replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

This would first replace all `\` with `\\` and then all `"` with `\"` if that is what you want.

Note that doing it the other way round would result in `"` being replaced with `\\"` in the end, since first it get replaced with `\"` and then the `\` would be replaced with `\\` resulting in `\\"`.

Additional note: your data string is not well-formed and should not compile: it ends in `\"` which is not a valid string literal delimiter (the literal ends in `\\\\\"` which would be the string data `\\"`) - change that to an even number of slashes or add another `"` to the end in order to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

The former.  The latter is not well-formed Java code.

Answer (score 0):

Since "String result = a.replace(""", "\"");" does not compile, does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

you a string error,Less a quote

String a = "data=\"0\"1\"1\"1\"1\"0\"0\"0\"0\"0\"0\"1\"1\"1\"1\"0\"0\"0\"0\"0\"1\"1\"1\"1\"1\\\"";

System.out.println(a.replace("\"", "\\\""));